# How to use Vue-IMask with Vuetify in Vue.js 2.5+

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can I use [Vue-IMask](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/vue-imask) directive on [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) controls specially **v-text-field**? It works on HTML input but I got error on v-text-field.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vue-imask` directive appears to be incompatible with Vuetify elements because it expects the element to be an `<input>`, but `<v-text-field>` resolves to a `<div>` (with several inner elements that comprise a custom input). While the docs show an [example](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/3acd703/packages/vue-imask#mask-stateless-example) where you could use IMask via a computed property, potentially bound to any `v-model` (perhaps including `<v-text-field>`), I was not able to get the example to work with any element.

You might consider using `<v-text-field>` with a different masking library, such as [`vue-the-mask`](https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/), as recommended in the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#masks-using-vue-the-mask).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-text-field v-mask="['(###)###-####', '#-###-###-####', '###-###-####']" placeholder="Enter phone number" />
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-the-mask@0.11.1/dist/vue-the-mask.js"></script>
  <script>
    Vue.use(VueTheMask)
    
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify()
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that it was a feature of Vuetify 1.5, that is removed in the version of today (2.2.16)

Comment: @AdrienClerc Thanks. I updated the answer with a demo, using a third party library.